# How do I get the current browser URL with purescript?

Tags: purescript

How do I get the the browser URL in Purescript, just like when doing  `window.location.href` in javascript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import Web.HTML (window)
import Web.HTML.Window (location)
import Web.HTML.Location (pathname)
import Effect.Console (log)



main :: Effect Unit
main = do
  l <- window >>= location >>= pathname
  log $ l
```